# Command Line Parser Library parsing a List of Enums

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments, command-line-parser

I'm trying to get a list of enums as an option.

```
[OptionList('m', "modules", HelpText = "List of modules you are going to install or uninstall.")]
public List<RegistrationType> Modules { get; set; }
```

Unfortunately it expects it to be a list of strings. Any idea on how to make it work as documentation of the lib is a bit short.

Thanks

Comment: Just ran into this one too.  Documentation says enums are supported but complains about converting from string.

Answer (score 4):

As of Nov 2018, there is a support for `IEnumerable<TEnum>` (package version [2.3.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommandLineParser/2.3.0)):

```
[Option('m', "modules", Separator = ',', HelpText = "List of modules...")]
public IEnumerable<RegistrationType> Modules { get; set; }
```

Sample parse (has changed since the question was asked):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Parser.Default.ParseArguments<Options>(args)
        .WithParsed(options => ...)
}
```

Sample command line:

```
myProject.exe -m RegistrationType1,RegistrationType2
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, it doesn't support any list other than IList. Any type but string :(

Sorry. It seems that this library is very powerful, but has very little documentation about it.